# QUERY() ignores query when combined with array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

Please consider the following Google Spreadsheet Formula:

```
=QUERY(
    ARRAYFORMULA({
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!A1:A"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SB1:SB"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SA1:SA"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!CY1:GP")
    }),
    "SELECT * WHERE Col2 <> 0 AND Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
```

The Query expression won't work. I've tried to modify everything with it, but it always yields the same results. Is this caused by the interaction between `QUERY()` and `ARRAYFORMULA`, or by `{}`?

In other cases I would prefer doing this by importing the whole range and selecting the Cols as i please, but keep in mind that the last imported range adds up to 96 Columns, so this solution grows unpractical pretty fast.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Usually, ARRAYFORMULA is added just next of the first `=`:  ` =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(..`. Anyway, I don't know why you  formula doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured it out somehow by adding an extra array `{}`. No idea why this is working, but hey...

```
=QUERY({
    ARRAYFORMULA({
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!A1:A"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SB1:SB"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SA1:SA"),
            IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!CY1:GP")
    })},
    "SELECT * WHERE Col2 <> 0 AND Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case you don't need to use ARRAYFORMULA at all.
Your curly braces array-ify the IMPORTRANGE results, which QUERY can parse.

You should be able to write your formula as:

```
=QUERY({
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!A1:A"),
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SB1:SB"),
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SA1:SA"),
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!CY1:GP")
},
"SELECT * WHERE Col2 <> 0 AND Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
```

*Note that plain commas will push the results out in to new columns.*

To have the results in a single column or columns as you normally expect to see when using QUERY, substitute semicolons in place of the commas within the curly braces:

```
=QUERY({
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!A1:A");
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SB1:SB");
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!SA1:SA");
        IMPORTRANGE("f333fHFF5sf6YxO4342Y4BIV3242KJTaarqU","Sample!CY1:GP")
},
"SELECT * WHERE Col2 <> 0 AND Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
```

**Generic sample that other people can use**
(kindly hosted by someone else)

Wide-format - note commas

```
=QUERY(
{IMPORTRANGE("1UDEdV70XTxw7fCFna6wSS7XYkZsSKm5rVgZL3uCsD4k","Sheet1!A1:C"),
IMPORTRANGE("1w5ILzQcW5xokFVFBpcYVumjKXzuLdII0iEjX8P52WiA","Sheet1!A1:C"),
IMPORTRANGE("153DPunGmabPPfLg9wx7VDOZc9GxZTc-sUlkSHk8DDK0","Sheet1!A1:C")},
"Select *",1)
```

Narrow-format - note semi-colons

```
=QUERY(
{IMPORTRANGE("1UDEdV70XTxw7fCFna6wSS7XYkZsSKm5rVgZL3uCsD4k","Sheet1!A1:C");
IMPORTRANGE("1w5ILzQcW5xokFVFBpcYVumjKXzuLdII0iEjX8P52WiA","Sheet1!A1:C");
IMPORTRANGE("153DPunGmabPPfLg9wx7VDOZc9GxZTc-sUlkSHk8DDK0","Sheet1!A1:C")},
"Select *",1)
```

*Remember to use each of these IMPORTRANGE samples individually and authorise before trying to embed them in the QUERY.*